# Nested Case Statement Returning Zero

Tags: sql

I'm sure this is a simple question but I feel I have been looking at this for so long now without any progress. I'm trying to calculate a final column using a CASE statement based on a nested query.

```
SELECT ID,Category, MaxBand, MinBand, Value, Company_Cost,
       CASE WHEN Company_Cost > MaxBand THEN MaxBand
       ELSE Company_Cost
       END AS Final_Company_Cost
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, Category, MaxBand, MinBand, Value,
           CASE WHEN (Value - MinBand) > 0 THEN (Value- MinBand)
           ELSE 0
           END AS Company_Cost
    FROM #TempTable
) T1
```

The table data that I'm looking at is below:

```
    ID      Category  MaxBand   MinBand   Value     Company_Cost Final_Comapny_Cost
    11548   1         0         0         8478121   8478121      0 
    11548   2         50000     0         417732    417732       50000
```

Essentially I'm trying to make the Final_Company_Cost column have 8478121 and 50000 as there is no Max Band on Category 1 but it keeps returning zero.

Any help would be much appreciate.

Comment: Case expressions, not case statements.

Comment: Ha Ha jarlh you scoop the award for possibly the least helpful comment I have ever read. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, i understood your question correctly.

Please  check if below query can help for what you are looking.

```
SELECT  ID,Category, MaxBand, MinBand, Value, Company_Cost,
CASE
    WHEN Company_Cost > MaxBand THEN Company_Cost  ELSE MaxBand -- changed here
END AS Final_Company_Cost FROM
(SELECT ID,Category, MaxBand, MinBand, Value,
        CASE
            WHEN (Value - MinBand) > 0 THEN (Value- MinBand) ELSE 0
        END AS Company_Cost

FROM #TempTable) T1
```

Comment: Thanks Tajinder for your quick reply, this has given me the 8478121 in row 1 that I was looking for but also given me 417732 in row 2 instead of capping it at 50000 because there is a value in MaxBand. Any ideas?

Comment: Please confirm if i am getting you right you want to get the Final_Company_Cost for category 2 on the basis of Max Band on Category 1

Comment: I want to pull through the Company_Cost into the Final_Company_Cost if the value is greater than the value in the MaxBand if not pull through the MaxBand. So my final value should be 8478121 in Row 1 and 50000 in Row 2.

Comment: Thanks for thje clarification, now we see for category2 company_Cost= 417732 and maxBand = 50000 and 417732>50000. so,  Final_Company_Cost will be 417732

Comment: Thank you for you help Tajinder but as pointed out by Nathan I needed a fresh look at the way I was pulling the number through.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your `CASE` expression logic.

```
CASE WHEN Company_Cost > MaxBand THEN MaxBand
       ELSE Company_Cost
       END AS Final_Company_Cost
```

In English, you are saying when the company_cost value is greater than the MaxBand value then return the MaxBand value. If not, return the company_cost value.

For your example, you are hoping to return the company_cost value if it is greater than the MaxBand. That means the `CASE` expression should be updated to:

```
CASE WHEN Company_Cost > MaxBand THEN Company_Cost
       ELSE MaxBand
       END AS Final_Company_Cost
```

Sometimes talking through the logic out loud will help you find the errors in your expression.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I have tried to amend the query this way around but for some reason I cannot seem to pull through the ELSE MaxBand value. My Final_Company_Cost pulls through all the values in the relevant column and will not seem to mix across the two. So in your example I get 8478121 in row 1 and 417732 in row 2 rather than 50000

Comment: Row two is set to 417,732 which is greater than 50,000. Either you need to change the comparator logic or fix a typo in row two's value column. Perhaps you meant to have a max band at 500,000?

Comment: Of course! Thank you for pointing out the obvious, I have been staring at this for far too long. I have now gone for WHEN MaxBand = 0 Then Company_Cost Else MaxBand - Simple when you have a second pair of eyes. Thank you.

Comment: @Carlos80 glad it helped. If an answer is helpful, you should acknowledge the effort by giving it an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Check here:

```
CASE WHEN Company_Cost > MaxBand THEN MaxBand
       ELSE Company_Cost
       END AS Final_Company_Cost
```